# Adding a composite to a table in Eclipse view

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I wish to add a composite in a table below the table item when the user selects the table item. Is this possible. Basically it will be more details about the item.

Comment: If you only want this composite to be visible when the table item is "selected", then you may be able to use a `CellEditor`.

Answer (score 0):

SWT/JFace does not support this out of the box. Some suggestions:

- Implement a Master-Detail-View. Your table is the master view. Add a second detail view which listens to selections of the table view. Many Eclipse IDE views work like this i.e. the Property View. Provides loosly coupled classes and is open for additions. Recommended "eclipse way". Google selection service and master detail view.
- Add a double click listener or a context menu to your table to open an additional details popup.
- Add the detail info to the hover tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [Nebula CompositeTable Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/compositetable/compositetable.php)

> CompositeTable is a custom SWT grid control that:
>
> - Gives you control over the layout of your rows
> - Automatically edits in place using any SWT control
> - Manages CRUD operations simply and automatically
> - Requests only visible data using a virtual table API for maximum scalability and performance.